# Access $window.sessionStorage from html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my case I am working with angularjs and I want to access a saved value in *user* to show or not some html tags.

First it save in some controller the user variable, it is a part of log in action.

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem('user', AuthenticationService.getUser());
```

Then, I want to show some html tags depending on the role of that user, with something like the following:

```
<li><a id="id" ng-if="user.role=='admin'" href> console </a></li>
```

I had something similar to this using *$rootScope*, but when I refresh the page I lose the value. That is why I need to use *window.sessionStorage*

Is there any way to access in html a saved value in sessionStorage? or this is wrong and I need another approach?

Comment: Copy the value into a scope object in your controller's `ng-load` or in the body of the controller.

Comment: I would write a `Provider` in your position, the provider will run before the app runs, passing related auth info to it, based on that you can define weather or not you will show some tags.

Comment: @dman2306 if I refresh the page, do I lose the value which is store in that scope variable?

Comment: @IkerAguayo Not if you reload it from sessionStorage on each refresh.

Comment: @dman2306 in that case, the first approach with $rootScope is valid too, I do not want to reload nothing

Comment: Well the html can't access sessionStorage. You have to load the value into scope. That's just the way it works. You need either a scope method that accesses sessionStorage or to copy the sessionStorage variable into a scope variable. Those are the only options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$window is just a wrapper around window, so this approach will work, but it's more preferable to use some other means, such as cookies than to pollute $window.

You should use a controller function or even better, a global user service to access the user.

There's a pretty detailed article on how to do this here: http://www.nesterovsky-bros.com/weblog/2015/01/26/windowsessionStorageInAngularJS.aspx

If you have multiple user properties, use toJson and fromJson to store the object in session storage such as:

```
var user = { name:'mike', role: 'admin'}
$window.sessionStorage.setItem('user',angular.toJson(user));
```

and:

```
var user = angular.fromJson($window.sessionStorage.getItem('user'))
```

If you need to access the user from a number of different places, a service like 
@Deblaton recommended is the way to go, but assuming you have multiple properties on your user, add the angular.toJson and angular.fromJson lines like I have above.

The way you are accessing the user in your html requires that it's present on the current scope so if you use the service approach in your controller you would add:

```
$scope.user = UserService.getUser();
```

Comment: But what is what I have to put in the html?

Comment: You will need to inject the service into every controller that requires an authenticated user and call a function to get the user or you can also handle this with routing. Typically if an unauthenticated user tries to access a page that requires authentication you would redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: So your answer means, set in every controller a method which calls that service to know the "user"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via a service/factory

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("PrincipalService", [
    "$window",
    function($window){

        var user;

        return {
            getUser : getUser,
            setUser: setUser
        };

        function getUser(){
            return user || angular.fromJson($window.sessionStorage.getItem('user'));
        }

        function setUser(userInfo){
            user = userInfo;
            $window.sessionStorage.setItem('user', angular.toJson(userInfo));
        }

    }
]);
```

**edit**

The way I could use it to share through every views via rootScope :

```
angular.module("myApp").run(["$rootScope", "PrincipalService",
    function($rootScope, PrincipalService){
        $rootScope.getUser = PrincipalService.getUser;
        $rootScope.setUser = PrincipalService.setUser;
    }
]);
```

And then, in your views you can call :

```
<span>{{$root.getUser()}}</span>
```

Comment: And should I call a controller method which calls this factory to get the user and then put it the html? Because I have several controllers and I do not want to repeat the same method in every one.

Comment: I cannot use this solution, because the user info is loaded after a sign in, and the run methods is executed before that. But I give you +1 because with a part of your solution I implement something that works

Comment: @IkerAguayo My service is only returning methods to get and set user information. It should not be strictly bound to your authentication process. Your authentication can use the service I posted to store user information, but you do not want to change your whole app the day your authentication process will have to change.